# Strange characters in ansi-term in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, ascii, emacs23, emacs24

I wrote a c++ program and when I compiled it using g++ in ansi-term, I got some strange characters displayed:

[image]

If required, the error was that i hadn't declared the variable n. How can I correct this?

Comment: Looks like you're using `gccfilter` or something similar to color your output.  Those are terminal escape sequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah! Tested this...

```
 (setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

and problem solved!!!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the `gcc` output contains UTF-8 "smart quotes" and your terminal is not set up to display UTF-8.  The simple workaround is to use a `locale` which does not support smart quotes inside Emacs, which should force `gcc` to fall back to plain-jane ASCII quotes; a more sophisticated fix would be to fix the terminal mode in the Ansi-Term buffer to display these correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Those are most likely color escape sequences.  emacs has a mode for that which you can enable with the `ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on` function.

Comment: @sudeepdino008 - does it do anything?

Comment: No.Nothing. I tried it in various ways, nothing happened. No message, nothing.

Comment: @sudeepdino008 - what happens if you run 'ls --color=tty' in the terminal window?

Comment: @sudeepdino008 - also, what is the value of the "TERM" environment variable?

Comment: right. so when i do ls --color=tty', i get folders and files listed in different colours. And when i do echo $TERM, i get eterm-color.

Comment: @sudeepdino008 - so, ansi term color stuff is "working", but somehow the tool you are using is spitting out weird color sequences.  what tool specifically are you using which is generating those?

Comment: what do you mean by which tools i am using?

Comment: @sudeepdino008 - what is genarting the color sequences?